# Show there's no integer between $x_n$ and $y_n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, square-numbers

For positive integers $n$, let $x_n, y_n$ be defined as:

$x_n = \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}$ and $y_n = \sqrt{4n + 2}$

Show that there is no whole number between $x_n$ and $y_n$.

Observation:
Obviously $x_n \not\in \mathbb{N}$ since $n$ and $n+1$ cannot both be perfect squares and $y_n \not\in \mathbb{N}$ since $4n +2 \equiv 2 \textrm{ (mod 4)}$ and any square must be $\equiv 0 \textrm{ or } 1 \textrm{ (mod 4)}$.

Question from 2009 German Math Olympiad, 2nd round

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Should be a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456333/mathematical-induction-involving-the-floor-function?noredirect=1), once you see why your question is answered by the result in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward approach can be as below;

Assume $m^2\lt n \le (m+1)^2$. Hence;

$$2m \lt \sqrt n+ \sqrt {n+1}\lt \sqrt {4n+2} \lt 2m+3.$$

Therefore $k$ (the integer between $x_n$ and $y_n$) is either $2m+1$ or $2m+2$. But It is impossible for $k$ to be $2m+2$ because, in this manner, $n$ has to be $(m+1)^2$ (note that $\sqrt {4((m+1)^2-1)+2} \lt 2m+2$) while;

$$(m+1)+(m+1)\lt \sqrt n+ \sqrt {n+1}\lt 2m+2,$$
which is a contradiction.

Now, if $k=2m+1$, we must have:

$$\sqrt {4n+2}\gt 2m+1\implies n\gt m^2+m-\frac{1}{4} \implies n\ge m^2+m. $$

But, in this case, we must also have:

$$\sqrt{m^2+m}+\sqrt {m^2+m+1}\le \sqrt n+ \sqrt {n+1}\lt 2m+1, $$

which is impossible; because for every integer $m$, we have:

$$\sqrt{m^2+m}+\sqrt {m^2+m+1}\gt 2m+1.$$